# Using Set -e , how to make exception for one command

Tags: shell, unix

Using `set -e` in the shell script can let the process
exit immediately if one of the commands exits with a non-zero status

However, if I want to exclude one command, so that if that specific command exits with non-zero value, the process continues.

Comment: See the [exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), and the list of incompatibilities between different shells' implementations at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/,  in evaluating whether `set -e` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule, don't use `set -e`.  Second rule, see rule 1.  The implementation of `set -e` has strange behavior in edge cases, and has changed through various versions of shells.  It is safest not to use it.  However, you can suppress it simply by making your command part of a compound command.  That is, instead of

`cmd_which_may_fail`

you can simply do:

`cmd_which_may_fail || true`

Now, if `cmd_which_may_fail` does fail, the script will not exit.

Note that is is sometimes tempting (and you will often see code that does this) to do something like `cmd_which_may_fail || echo 'command failed!' >&2`, but you really should not do that.  Instead, allow `cmd_which_may_fail` to emit a reasonable error message (most common commands do, and if you have a command that doesn't emit good error messages you might want to reconsider using it at all), since that process will have context and can write a useful error message.  `Command failed` is generally considered a useless error message.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do

```
command ||:
```

the return status of `:` is zero. If `command` returns nonzero status, then `:` is executed, which returns zero status. If `command` returns a zero status, then `:` is not executed. In both cases - the return status is zero, ie. success.

I've seen:

```
command |:
```

Well... it's one character shorter, but binding stdout to `:` process seems like a waste of cpu time for me. The return status of the pipe is the return status of the last executed command, and it's `:`. But this can fail when `set -o pipefail`, so I wouldn't recommend it.

You can run a command in a subshell:

```
( set +e; command; )
```

this allows for more flexibility, but you need to add `(` before the command and is far more typing.

Comment: `||:` is much better than `|:` for reasons beyond just CPU time -- with the `||:` formulation you can change shell state on the left-hand side without having changes isolated to a subshell; it also avoids all the fun signal-handling side effects, avoids rerouting file descriptors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`( set +e; command; )` do not work

`( set +e; command; true )` is the solution

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e
( set +e ; killall DUMMY_PROCESS_ABC )
echo happy end
```

This will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e
echo $( set +e ; killall DUMMY_PROCESS_ABC )
echo happy end
```

this also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e
(set +e ; killall DUMMY_PROCESS_ABC ; true)
echo happy end
```